# How to pull data from HTML

Tags: php, curl, raspberry-pi, domdocument

I am trying to write a PHP Script to pull snow and other data from http://www.snowbird.com/mountain-report to display via an LED array. I am having troubles with getting the data I need. I can't seem to be able to find a way to make it work. I've read about PHP not being the best tool for this? Would I be able to make this work, or would I have to go about and use a different language? Here is the code I cant seem to get working.

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');


// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();
// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.snowbird.com/mountain-report/");
//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);
// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);


$output = ($output);

$html = new DOMDocument();
$html = loadhtml( $content);

$ret1 = $html->find('div[id=twelve-hour]');
print_r ($ret1);
$ret2 = $html->find('#twenty-four-hour');
print_r ($ret2);
$ret3 = $html->find('#forty-eight-hour');
print_r ($ret3);
$ret4 = $html->find('#current-depth');
print_r ($ret4);
$ret5 = $html->find('#year-to-date');
print_r ($ret5);
?>
```

Comment: Please tell us, whats wrong with this code.

Comment: What do you get when you run this?

Comment: Running this I get 

    PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function loadhtml() in /var/www/test3.php on line 20

Comment: ah, `$html->loadhtml($content);` maybe?

Comment: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: content in /var/www/test3.php on line 20
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input in /var/www/test3.php on line 20
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method DOMDocument::find() in /var/www/test3.php on line 22

Comment: oh, `$content` was from your code. Looks like it should be `$output`.

Comment: Why don't you use `file_get_html` instead of curl query?

Comment: changing to $output I get PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method DOMDocument::find() in /var/www/test3.php on line 22. Sergey, would file_get_html be a good replacement for the curl query?

Comment: Why not? What the reason, you want to perform custom http request?

Comment: `find` isn't a method of `DOMDocument`. You are including `simple_html_dom.php` and then using a different class `DOMDocument` which is likely not what you want. Using domdocument you would need to either use an xpath query or just looking at your code `getElementById` would likely work.

Comment: Changing to File_get_html, I know get the errors: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.snowbird.com/mountain-report/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
 in /var/www/simple_html_dom.php on line 76
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /var/www/test4.php on line 8

@Jonathan, if find is now a method then how should I go and look for the data I want?

Comment: So, you've got server error. Code now is almost ok. If you want to make custom handler for this case - use any http lib(even guzzle or something like that).

Comment: @SergeyChizhik, sorry I not all that familiar with this area, can you maybe explain that a bit more in detail?

Comment: @knilssen, sure. You want to parse html source that you has gotten from server. So, it requires three steps: get html(and store to string), parse html(from string), get needed data. First step you can perform manually if you want to handle such errors like `500 server error`, `400 bad request`, `404 not found`, etc. If request was successful - you can make parsing. How? If I'm not mistaken you are using [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) lib, so `str_get_html` allows you to parse string that you has gotten from server. Finally - you getting needed data using `find` method.

Comment: All examples I've seen [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Comment: @SergeyChizhik, I believe I have accomplished what you just said but my print_r are returning empty..... So I did $ret1 = $html->find('div[id]');
print_r ($ret1);

and what I got was no where near html. Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: `<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$ch = curl_init("http://www.snowbird.com/mountain-report/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($content);


$ret1 = $html->find('div[id]');
print_r ($ret1);
$ret2 = $html->find('#twenty-four-hour');
print_r ($ret2);
$ret3 = $html->find('#forty-eight-hour');
print_r ($ret3);
$ret4 = $html->find('#current-depth');
print_r ($ret4);
$ret5 = $html->find('#year-to-date');
print_r ($ret5);


?> `

Comment: This code works fine for me. I see results normaly.

Comment: Where you able to get the snow results?

Comment: I've just inserted your code to `test php`, and exec it from console `php test.php`. Also I've tried to run with php built-in server and got result.

Comment: My results are `php test4.php
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)`

Answer (score 0):

This is an ancient question, but it's easy enough to provide an answer for it. Use an [XPath query](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to get the correct node's text value. (This should be as easy as passing the URL directly to `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile()` but the server is requests based on user agent so we have to fake it.)

```
<?php

$ctx = stream_context_create(["http"=>[
    "user_agent"=>"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"
]]);
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.snowbird.com/mountain-report/", true, $ctx);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_NOWARNING|LIBXML_NOERROR);
$xp = new DomXpath($doc);
$root = $doc->getElementById("snowfall");

$snowfall = [
    "12hour" => $xp->query("div[@id='twelve-hour']/div[@class='total-inches']/text()", $root)->item(0)->textContent,
    "24hour" => $xp->query("div[@id='twenty-four-hour']/div[@class='total-inches']/text()", $root)->item(0)->textContent,
    "48hour" => $xp->query("div[@id='forty-eight-hour']/div[@class='total-inches']/text()", $root)->item(0)->textContent,
    "current" => $xp->query("div[@id='current-depth']/div[@class='total-inches']/text()", $root)->item(0)->textContent,
    "ytd" => $xp->query("div[@id='year-to-date']/div[@class='total-inches']/text()", $root)->item(0)->textContent,
];

print_r($snowfall);
```